Preventing NULL Overwrite in SQLite when Updating from Joined Table"
I'm working with an SQLite database and facing an issue when trying to update one table based on the content of another while avoiding NULL overwrites. Here are the details:
Database Structure:
tweets: Contains columns id (INTEGER) and text (TEXT).
extended_tweets: Contains columns tweet_id (INTEGER, foreign key referencing tweets.id) and full_text (TEXT).
I need to update the text in the tweets table with the full_text from the extended_tweets table, but only when full_text is not null. The problem occurs when the update command seems to sometimes set text to null even when I use COALESCE to default to the existing value of text if full_text is null. This is happening despite conditions that supposedly prevent such an outcome.
here is the sql command I have tried already.
UPDATE tweets
SET text = (
    SELECT COALESCE(full_text, text)
    FROM extended_tweets
    WHERE tweet_id = tweets.id
    AND full_text IS NOT NULL
)
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT tweet_id
    FROM extended_tweets
    WHERE full_text IS NOT NULL
);

Instead of retaining the original text when full_text is null, text gets set to null when full_text for the corresponding id.
I want the text in tweets should be updated only with non-null full_text values. If full_text is null, text should remain unchanged.
Could anyone help clarify why the COALESCE isn't preventing the null overwrite or suggest an alternative approach to ensure text remains unchanged when full_text is null?
